# Role of PHP file in PWA

Tags: php, progressive-web-apps

I am new to the PWA. So I was trying to create a basic website. which include 
index.html, 
manifest,
serviceworker file,
answer.php.
Answer.php is running on server. on clicking a button in index.html, it goes to answer.php where data is obtained from the database. I am caching all the files except serviceworker and answer.php.

Q1: Should I cache answer.php?

Q2: If not, then how can I connect it to indexed db (represent data obtained from server in the form of html file).

Q3: what is the role of server files in PWA.

Comment: On distinction to keep in mind. Service workers will not cache `answer.php` offline, it will cache the rendered output of `answer.php`.

Answer (score 0):

*Q1: Should i cache answer.php?*

**I don't think so, since its generating data querying the database.**

*Q2: If not, then how can i connect it to indexed db (represent data obtained from server in the form of html file).*

**You can use answer.php to return a JSON to your PWA:** [Manual JSON Encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#refsect1-function.json-encode-returnvalues)

*Q3: what is the role of server files in PWA*

**Any backend services.** I.E.: [How to build a JSON backend with PHP](https://alexwebdevelop.com/php-json-backend/)